# Creating a for loop for a bezier curve

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't figure out how to create a for loop that allows me to make 100 bezier curves across my canvas from left to right.  I have the code to make the shape of the curve I want, I just can't figure out how to have it replicate across the page. Please help! This is what I am trying to do, but without having to repeat the code a 100 times.

```
var canvas       
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx;
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(10,10,40,10,80,10);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.shadowColor;
ctx.fillStyle("#FF0000");

var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(50,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(175,330,-15,600,0,600);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-100,700,50,800,0,850);
ctx.moveTo(62.5,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(187.5,330,-2.5,600,12.5,600);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-87.5,700,62.5,800,12.5,850);

ctx.moveTo(75,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(200,330,10,600,25,600);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-75,700,75,800,25,850);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: You have a type on your `canvas` element. `"style="border:1 px solid #c3c3c3;"` should be: `style="border:1 px solid #c3c3c3;"`

Comment: So you want the same curve repeated 100 times on the canvas? You need to adjust the position of all points, otherwise you will create multiple curves that looks exactly the same (so it will look like there is just one of them).

Comment: ctx.fillStyle("#FF0000"); should be ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

Comment: It's a good idea to run through a few basic programming lessons so you're exposed to and can familiarise yourself with the basics of code control (like for loops, function calls, recursion, etc). Something like Daniel Shiffman's "the coding train" is generally a great starting point for beginners, since it uses a java-like language (which is general enough that the basic programming concepts carry over to any other language) that has immediately visible results.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop . And check for the pattern.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
 var j = 12.5*i;
 ctx.moveTo(50+j, 0);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(175+j, 330, -15+j, 600, j, 600);
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(-100+j, 700, 50+j, 800, j, 850);
}

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="1200" height="1000" style="border:1 px solid #c3c3c3; ">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same curve repeated 100 times on the canvas, you need to adjust the position of all points, otherwise you will create multiple curves that looks exactly the same (so it will look like there is just one of them).

Also there were some syntactic errors in your code, e.g. `fillStyle` is a property, not a function.

Create a function for the drawing, that will take [x, y] coordinates from where to draw the curve:

```js
function drawCurve(ctx, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + 20, y + 20);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 10, y + 10, x + 40, y + 10, x + 80, y + 10);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawCurve(ctx, 50, 30);
drawCurve(ctx, 150, 130);
drawCurve(ctx, 0, 90);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width ="1200" height="1000" style="border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [for](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) loop.

You may also want to replace some of the hard-coded constants in your function calls with variables that are incremented or decremented inside of the loop. This should make the output more dynamic.